# BAD_ACCESS while trying to instantiate UIAlertView

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to instantiate UiAlertView like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                      initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                      message:@"Incorrect login or password."
                                      delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

It's after I get response from server that session expired. App throws me back to login screen then. And then I'm trying to log in with incorrect data, but alert won't show. Instead it throws something like this:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib               0x33aa15b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                         0x3a39a370 -[UILabel _setText:] + 92
2   UIKit                         0x3a4e6648 -[UIAlertView
initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:] + 64
3   MY APP                       0x00039c7e 0x34000 + 23678
4   MY APP                        0x0005f784 0x34000 + 178052
5   MY APP                       0x000756be 0x34000 + 267966
6   Foundation                    0x347d28e8 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 456
7   CoreFoundation                0x32bbd680
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
8   CoreFoundation                0x32bbcee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
9   CoreFoundation                0x32bbbcb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
10  CoreFoundation                0x32b2eeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
11  CoreFoundation                0x32b2ed44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices              0x3a92c2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                         0x3a3ea2f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  MY APP                       0x0003527e 0x34000 + 4734
15  MY APP                       0x000351dc 0x34000 + 4572
```

Is it something with allocating strings created with @ or what?

EDIT:
I'm adding some more code due to request. I don't think server response function is relevant, since it just executex logOut method. By the way, the whole code I'm posting is placed in AppDelegate

```
- (void) logout
{
    isLogged = NO;
    currentUser = nil;
    [self createNotLoggedIn];
}
```

Then create notLoggedIn method creates UIViewController for login form.

```
-(void) createNotLoggedIn
{

    UIViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

    //UINavigationControllers are created here... stripped    

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navLoginViewController, navGrafikLekarzyViewController, navPlacowkiViewController, navWiecejViewController, nil];

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   
}
```

logOut and createNotLoggedIn are placed in AppDelegate

Comment: if you have  `UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>` in your h file you may need to change `delegate:nil` to `delegate:self`

Comment: I don't have that, but already tried such trick

Comment: enable guard malloc and zombies try to get an detail error before above thread details

Comment: I don't know how to use that. CHecked Enable Guard Malloc, Enable Zombie Objects and in Logging Disturbed Objects, Garbage Collection Activity and Malloc Stack. But I don;t see anything new in console

Comment: @SpaceDust Delegation has nothing to do with premature deallocation.  Show us the whole function for the server response.

Comment: Are you showing the alertview on the main thread?

Comment: @AlexL not sure, but I guess so. It's executed in AppDelegate by the way

Comment: @CodaFi sorry for the delay, christmas :) I exceeded the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the code that is showing AlertDialog to AppDelegate when the ViewController is created and it works

Answer (score 1):

The stack shows that the crash occurs in an internal, text related, setter method. So the source of the problem it probably one of the strings that you pass as arguments.

Set a breakpoint and check the strings in the debugger. Or enable zombies.

Comment: where should I see zombies logs? I enabled everything following instructions but I see nothing special in th debugger console

Comment: After enabling zombie detection in the schema you should see zombie accesses logged in the console. Also, the debugger should break at the point of access.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the following:

```
1   UIKit  0x3a39a370 -[UILabel _setText:] + 92
```

This line is setting some text on your label but it appears to be null or nil or empty.

Hope it helps,

Regards,

Reno Jones

Comment: how can it be empty since it's exactly this parth: message:@"Incorrect login or password."